# Spring ACL using JPA but ACL impl is JDBC. Two ways

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I have a dilema. I am using spring-security-acl and their jdbc implementation. Problem is, that I use JPA repository (Spring-data-jpa) in other queries. I think, that is no problem because JPA is implemented:

> ```
> <jpa:repositories base-package="cz.repository" />
>
>   <beans:bean id="myEmf"
>       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
>       <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
>       <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="cz.models" />
>       <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
>           <beans:bean
>               class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
>
>       </beans:property>
>       <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
>           <beans:props>
>
>               <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
>               </beans:prop>
>               <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
>           </beans:props>
>       </beans:property>
>   </beans:bean>
>
>   <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
>       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
>       <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
>   </beans:bean>
> ```

so I have allready datasource in this JPA and it is no problem with spring-security which use JDBC directly.

But problem is in **transactions**.

I am using

> ```
>   <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
>       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
>       <beans:property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
>   </beans:bean>
> ```

but spring-acl jdbc want

```
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

When I want implement ACL to my project I:

```
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("permitAll")
public Room createRoom(Integer roomID) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    createAcl(roomID);
    return roomRepository.save(roomID);

}
```

but I use **@Transactional** for

> org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager

instead of jdbc

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

Not often but sometime I have:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transaction must be running
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:65)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createOrRetrieveSidPrimaryKey(JdbcMutableAclService.java:218)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createObjectIdentity(JdbcMutableAclService.java:152)
    at org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService.createAcl(JdbcMutableAclService.java:107)
    at cz.services.RepositoryRoomService.createAcl(RepositoryRoomService.java:118)
```

I do not have that deep knowledge of transacitons for JDBC, so will be problem add

> org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

and have two transaction managers? 
There is another option write my own acl service instead of JdbcMutableAclService. But with jdbc it is easier solution.

```
<beans:bean id="aclService"
        class="org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.JdbcMutableAclService">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="lookupStrategy" />
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="aclCache" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Can please someone tell me what is better?

Or use JDBC with JPA is not good solution and use only one of that technology?
Thanks for answer

Comment: JpaTransactionManager should work for both JPA and JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest dont use the same transactionManager name in both transactional Managers, consider change the id of one of them

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager"

<beans:bean id="transactionManagerJPA"
```

then

```
@Transactional("transactionManagerJPA")
```

Or consider mark you methods with `@TransactionalAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer,but I do not use both transactionManager, only JPA. Sometime transaction is closed (in some cases). I try write my own JPAMutableAclService. Or do you have some faster and easier solution?